# How do I get the network interface and its right IPv4 address?

Tags: c#, ip-address, network-interface

I need to know how to get all network interfaces with their [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address. *Or just wireless and Ethernet.*

To get all network interfaces details I use this:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
    if(ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
       ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) {

        Console.WriteLine(ni.Name);
    }
}
```

And to get the all hosted IPv4 addresses of the computer:

```
IPAddress [] IPS = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in IPS) {
    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {

        Console.WriteLine("IP address: " + ip);
    }
}
```

But how to get the network interface and its right ipv4 address?

Comment: Please read a little more carefully. See [GetIPProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getipproperties.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders okay i have checked your link read it .. and tried it .. but i didn't get the IPV4 Address !! like 192.168.1.25 !!

Comment: Ok, it's a little more subtle than I thought. See [IPGlobalProperties.GetUnicastAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties.getunicastaddresses.aspx)

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
foreach(NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
   if(ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ni.Name);
       foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
       {
           if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(ip.Address.ToString());
           }
       }
   }  
}
```

This should get you what you want.  ip.Address is an IPAddress, that you want.

Comment: @Joseph your link is dead :/

Comment: @Felk thanks, this is the original url https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ff82643c9a004281544a

Answer (score 9):

One line with Lamda:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

var ipV4s = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .Select(i => i.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
    .SelectMany(u => u)
    .Where(u => u.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    .Select(i => i.Address);
```

Answer (score 5):

These answers lead me in the right direction - thanks to previous authors!
For anyone looking for plug and play methods, here is what worked for me.

```
public System.Net.IPAddress GetIpAddress()
{
    return NetworkInterface
        .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        .Where(n => n.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 || n.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
        .Where(n => n.Name == "Wi-Fi")
        .SelectMany(n => n.GetIPProperties()?.UnicastAddresses)
        .Where(n => n.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        .Select(g => g?.Address)
        .Where(a => a != null)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}

public System.Net.IPAddress GetDefaultGateway()
{
    return NetworkInterface
        .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
        .Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        .Where(n => n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
        .SelectMany(n => n.GetIPProperties()?.GatewayAddresses)
        .Select(g => g?.Address)
        .Where(a => a != null)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With some improvement, this code adds any interface to a combination:

```
private void LanSetting_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if ((nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) || (nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)) //&& (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up))
        {
            comboBoxLanInternet.Items.Add(nic.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

And when selecting one of them, this code returns the IP address of the interface:

```
private void comboBoxLanInternet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in nic.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
        {
            if (nic.Description == comboBoxLanInternet.SelectedItem.ToString())
            {
                if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ip.Address.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```