# Get IP Address on Monotouch/Xamarin in iphone via linq

Tags: c#, ios, linq, ip-address

I'm new to linq, and want to use it to get the ip address of an iOS device.  I was wondering if anyone sees any problems with this approach (based on this [How do I get the network interface and its right IPv4 address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855230/how-to-get-the-network-interface-and-its-right-ipv4-address) ) or if there is a better/more compact/more clean way to do it.

```
  // get my IP
  string ip = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("en0"))
      .Select(n => n.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
      .Where(x => x.First().Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
      .Select(x => x.First().Address.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with your code lies with the last `Select`. 
The `Where` selector already returns an `IEnumerable`, which means at that point you have an `IEnumerable` of `UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection`. Then at that point, just select the first one and point to the address property and convert to string using: `.First().Address.ToString()`

Here's an example that did the job for me:

```
public string IpEndPoint
    {
        get
        {
            return NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
           .Where(ni => ni.Name.Equals("en0"))
           .First().GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
           .Where(add => add.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
           .First().Address.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This seems to fail while using on mobile data.But, works fine on WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting `.First().Address` only once:

```
string ip = NetworkInterface
               .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
               .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("en0"))
               .Select(n => n.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.First().Address)
               .Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
```

Comment: I ended up using this.. var ip = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(x => x.Name.Equals("en0")).First().GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.Where(x=>x.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First().Address.ToString();