# Get iOS device ip address in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ip

hi can you please tell me how to access iOS device ip address using xamarin. we are building iOS app in which we want to show device local ip address. I used many other solutions but they didnt work for me.

Comment: hello guys it work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843925/get-ip-address-on-monotouch-xamarin-in-iphone-via-linq dont forget to vote him.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get IP Address on Monotouch/Xamarin in iphone via linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843925/get-ip-address-on-monotouch-xamarin-in-iphone-via-linq)

Answer (score 1):

I found a post about it here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/348/acquire-device-ip-addresses-monotouch-since-ios6-0

it goes as follow:
Try using System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface:

```
foreach (var netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
    netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) {
    foreach (var addrInfo in netInterface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses) {
        if (addrInfo.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
            var ipAddress = addrInfo.Address;

            // use ipAddress as needed ...
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: thanks for quick reaponse we alreadu tried this but it doesnt work for us.

Comment: Did you get an error ? you also need permissions to acces this interface I think?