# UdpClient not working in Multiple LAN Adapter System

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, udp, lan

I am new in `Socket Programming`. I am trying to create an application that sends data over the `UDP protocol`. I am using `UdpClient` for the communication it works well.

Now the conditions are different I have `two LAN Adapter` in my System.

The application not working if I connect one with the Internet and one with the other System.

```
UdpClient udpclient = new UdpClient(5555);
```

I create the socket using above but When I trace in Wireshark the application not sending any data.
So can anyone tell me how to make a socket so that it will work when there are two LAN Adapter?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

when using more than 1 adapter, the client will bind on the first one. th ensure the client binds on the correct adapter, you can use on of the other constructors.

```
 UdpClient client = new UdpClient(
            new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("##Ip address here##"), 5555));
```

this will make sure that the clients is working on the address you need.

Comment: And how to get the IP address of that Adapter

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855230/how-do-i-get-the-network-interface-and-its-right-ipv4-address